# Get random element of dictionary in TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, dictionary

I am trying to implement code that will return me a random element of a dictionary in TypeScript. So far, I've tried this:

```
dict = {
    0: "example 1",
    1: "example 2",
    2: "example 3"
  }

randomGen() { 
    var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * (3));
    console.log(this.dict[num])
  }
```

However this is throwing me an error:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'number' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; }

Is there a way around this? How can I randomly select an element from my dictionary?

Comment: You'll probably have to typecast the random number to `0 | 1 | 2`, i don't think there is a chance TS can semantically analyze the code, and see, that it can only produce those values.

Comment: When I convert the num to a string I get the same error. It says "Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type '{ 0: string; 1: string; 2: string; }"

That shows up when I run console.log(this.dicty[num.toString()])

Comment: Why not use an array?

Comment: @Jesse I can, it's just that with the quantity of elements I will need it might get disorganized for me. I just find it easier to read when it's in dictionary format, but if that's not an option I will go with array :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go.  I use the dictionary you created and randomly select a number based on the length of the dictionary (which are your keys).  Then return the value of the random key.

Here is for Typescript (test in https://www.typescriptlang.org/play):

```
var dict: {[key: number]: string} = {
    0: "example 1",
    1: "example 2",
    2: "example 3"
  }

function randomGen() { 
    var value = dict[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(dict).length)];
    return value;
  }
 
console.log(randomGen());
```

And below is for basic JavaScript:

```js
var dict = {
    0: "example 1",
    1: "example 2",
    2: "example 3"
  }

function randomGen() { 
    var value = dict[Math.floor(Math.random() * Object.keys(dict).length)];
    return value;
  }
 
console.log(randomGen());
```

Comment: The key here is that `dict` is explicitly typed to have `number` indices.